# slideUp does not work when the parent is fadeOut after the slideUp animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

on http://yamikowebs.com/test/client0002/ I have it so when you click on contact, or login a shadowBox fades in and then the necassary form slides down. When you hit the close button the form should slide up and than the shadowBox fades out...jQuery is having the whole thing fade out for some reason. What am i doing wrong?

```
//login
$('#header a[title="Sign In"], #login>button').click(function()
{
    if($('#login').is('visible'))
    {$('#login').slideUp(1000).parent('#shadowBox').delay(1000).fadeToggle(1000);}
    else{$('#shadowBox').fadeToggle(1000).children('#login').delay(1000).slideDown(1000);}
});
```

Comment: Try if($('#login').is(':visible')) instead of if($('#login').is('visible')). -> Difference is the :visible

Comment: >=( one of those typo moments... thank you =)

Comment: Going to put that in answers for closure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if($('#login').is(':visible'))` instead of `if($('#login').is('visible'))`.

Difference is the `:visible`